# How to write an apostrophe (') in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a reference with an apostrope ('). Biblatex compiles fine without it but doesn't when I add it. I use `biber` backend to compile.

The article title is then "Sur des méthodes d optimisation par relaxation" instead of "Sur des méthodes d'optimisation par relaxation".

I trie `\'`, `\'\`, `{\' }` but nothing worked.

Here's my bib file:

```
@article{test,
author = {Cea, J. and Glowinski, R.},
journaltitle = {ESAIM: Mathematical Modelling and Numerical Analysis - Mod{\'e}lisation Math{\'e}matique et Analyse Num{\'e}rique},
number = {R3},
pages = {5-31},
editor = {Dunod},
title = {Sur des m{\'e}thodes d optimisation par relaxation},
url = {http://eudml.org/doc/193251},
volume = {7},
year = {1973}
}
```

And a MWE file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
Test \cite{test}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I write that in my bib file?

Comment: I don't think `Sur des m{\'e}thodes d'optimisation par relaxation` would have problems.

Comment: Indeed I tried it with `d'optimisation` and it works fine here.

Comment: Off-topic: why don't you use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and then get to write your .bib file (and everything else) in a more natural way, such as `Sur des méthodes d'optimisation par relaxation` etc.?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. I'll try using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: I can't use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` as I need `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}` for another portion of code that I did not put in the MWE. But I cleaned the folder and the apostrophe just put as in worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: egreg's solution works for me.  What error do you get? (Look in the .log file for LaTeX or the .blg file biber).  On the other hand biber does issue a warning, but it is caused by the accented characters, not the apostrophe, and just information that is converting accents (back) to macros.

Comment: @egreg, care to answer it, for the sake of leaving it answered?

Comment: I did it (made it CW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following egreg's comment, just type the apostrophe directly and it should do. Like:

```
title = {Sur des m{\'e}thodes d'optimisation par relaxation},
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I shouldn't have left this one unanswered, sorry about that...